# Error plot matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, graphic

i have a list of functions:

```
[ x - 3^(1/2)/2, x - 4967757600021511/81129638414606681695789005144064, x + 3^(1/2)/2, x - 4160783518353059/4503599627370496, x - 1723452963400281/4503599627370496, x + 3446905926800561/9007199254740992, x + 4160783518353059/4503599627370496, x - 8566355544790271/9007199254740992, x - 2647149443198255/4503599627370496, x - 4967757600021511/81129638414606681695789005144064, x + 5294298886396509/9007199254740992, x + 8566355544790271/9007199254740992, x - 8700286382685973/9007199254740992, x - 2^(1/2)/2, x - 291404338770025/1125899906842624, x + 2331234710160199/9007199254740992, x + 2^(1/2)/2, x + 2175071595671493/2251799813685248, x - 8781369964030313/9007199254740992, x - 7042111946219083/9007199254740992, x - 3908077291623905/9007199254740992, x - 4967757600021511/81129638414606681695789005144064, x + 122127415363247/281474976710656, x + 880263993277385/1125899906842624, x + 4390684982015157/4503599627370496]
```

and I would like to plot the functions with this command "plot(funciones_che(1))" but when I make the plot throws me the following error:

```
Error using plot. A numeric or double convertible argument is expected
```

I have also tried x = -10: 10 and plot (x, funciones_che (1)) but I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a vector of functions. The variable `funciones_che` is just a long concatenated sequence of numbers. If you run `size(funciones_che)`, you should get `1 x m*n` where `m` is `length(x)` and `n` is the number of "functions" you have. Having a true vector of functions would actually complicate your life unnecessarily.

If you have a symbolic expression somewhere along the line, it may be a bit difficult to clear: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/clear-assumptions-and-reset-the-symbolic-engine.html. My recommendation is to reset the entire symbolic engine with all its assumptions just to be safe: `reset(symengine)`.

MATLAB is very good at plotting matrices like the one you have, but the size has to be right:

1. Separate your plots with semi-colons (`;`) rather than commas (`,`):

   ```
   funciones_che=[ x - 3^(1/2)/2; x - 4967757600021511/81129638414606681695789005144064; x + 3^(1/2)/2; .....]
   ```

   Now `size(funciones_che)` will be `n x m`.
2. Transpose the matrix (to make `plot` interpret it correctly):

   ```
   funciones_che = funciones_che';
   ```

   Now `size(funciones_che)` will be `m x n`.

Plot as you wanted to: `plot(funciones_che(:, 1))` for the first vector, or `plot(funciones_che)` to put all of them on the same plot. If you are not interested in the second version, you do not have to transpose the matrix. If you do not transpose the matrix, plot using `plot(funciones_che(1, :))` instead.

Final point: you do need to initialize `x`, for example to `-10:10` as you tried.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but gives me the same error. Error using plot. A numeric or double convertible argument is expected

Comment: How do you define `x`?

Comment: I define it as: x=-10:10;

Comment: Run `clear x funciones_che`, then `x=-10:10; funciones_che=...;` again.

Comment: You may have overwritten some variables with values of a weird type elsewhere

Comment: If that does not work, what is the output of `class(x)` and `class(funciones_che)`?

Comment: I cleaned all the workspace but gives me the same error :/

Comment: The code I have runs fine and produces a plot, but I removed the `.....`. Can you post the complete definition of the vector? And the result of `class(funciones_che)`?

Comment: class(x)=double and class(funciones_che)=sym

Comment: Ah. That would do it. I updated my response. Just run the reset command to make everything a `double` instead of a `sym`.

Comment: If you found this answer to be helpful, please select it as the correct one.